# Revert ubuntu mass manual install

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Some time ago, I reinstalled every package as manual in the aftermath of an accidental mistake.

I upgraded to 17.04 without many problems, but now with 17.10 I noticed this to be the root cause of a very slow startup time. Specifically, I seem to have some (or several) old packages which rely on old systemd-network units and which I don't need anymore. But as all packages are marked as manually installed, I see now way of getting rid of them easily.

Now, how can I reset the manual installation flag on every package to what it would have been had I done proper management? I'd like to avoid a reinstallation but would be fine with some software is missing after the fixing step, as long as I can boot into a running system (with network connectivity with NetworkManager and without deleting config files).

Edit: The specific mistake, I broke my Ubuntu 15.04 by deleting the complete `/bin` path. Instead of properly repairing it, I commanded `apt-get` to simply install every currently installed package on the system. I did mention that previously as it the detail appears a bit misleading.

Comment: There are solutions to your question, however, i recommend just reinstalling. Too much other configuration might have broken because postinst scripts simply are not prepared to fail gracefully for certain missing files.

Comment: It might have not been clear in the question but my system is currently bootable and running. It just takes 30 seconds to boot while waiting on a network timeout (from network-online.target). To my understanding, fixing should only remove packages. More precisely those which are currently marked as `manual` but should be marked as an orphan and removed. It is not clear to me how there would be missing files.

Comment: I don't believe to be missing any binaries currently (`debsums -c` comes back clean) and that is not at all where I was aiming at. All I'd like to do is unmark the `manual` flag on the to their normal state. Should that fail, a reinstall is always an option but one I'd like to avoid.